# Wifi not working on Thinkpad

Tags: wireless

Being new to Ubuntu...After reading several cases, I believe my problem is slightly different. On a Thinkpad T500, Ubuntu 18.04 sees the wifi, says it's on, connected to my router, but I cant get to anything. It appears data isn't flowing. I ran lshw -C network and it said itt is an intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection.
Using the GUI's status window I'm told it is connected with execellent signal strength with an IP address assigned. If I try to do software updates they fail, if I launch a browser it goes nowhere.....Thanks for any tips.

Comment: can you add the output of `iwconfig` `sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` to your question?

Comment: Could you also [edit] your question to include the "DNS configuration" output of `nmcli -p`? This may make it more likely that someone can quickly identify the issue and offer a solution 

Comment: Ok, this is bizarre, and befuddling, and you are probably not going to believe it but..I left the laptop on when I retired last night. When I got back to it this AM, the wifi was working AND the OS updated to 20.04!! Why? IDK, sunspots?  someone from AskUbunt came in secret and fixed it? Actually I'm responding from the system now. Sadly I don't know why it wasn't working, or why it is now. All I can say is that I installed the OS over a year ago and the laptop sat on the shelf until I powered it up after a long hibernation, and the stated results occurred. Thanks to those responding!